# Negotiating an Offer: Salary vs. Equity + Signing Bonus. Help!

Tags: negotiation, compensation

I'm thrilled to have received an offer I'm excited really excited about with a great company this past week. This is my first job out of graduate school, so I'm new to the whole negotiation thing.

The initial offer was 130k + 1,000 shares RSU (3-year vestment period). I asked for 150k in my counter, and received this response:

> I did get preliminary approval to up the offer to 140k (from 130),
>   1200 (from 1,000) shares, with a 5k signing bonus (to help with some
>   of the relo stuff).  Would that get you across the line or do you want
>   me to push for the 150k?

Now, frankly I'm very happy with this offer, but due to the language I'm thinking of asking for the 150k in exchange for scrapping the extra 200 shares and 5k signing bonus. My thinking is that a) all future raises and other offers will be based on the base salary, b) he says he only has "preliminary approval," so I will need to wait for a new written offer anyway, and c) he makes it sound likely that it could happen.

That said, I don't want to push my luck and I'd be happy with it as is. But if a single decision and an extra day or two of waiting means potentially tens of thousands of dollars down the road, I'll do the rational move.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the location?

Comment: San Francisco/Bay Area

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What is your practical question? We can't make decision for you

Comment: I don't think you need to give specific numbers on the bonus/RSU, just say that you're willing to be flexible on those in order to get to a good salary number, and is that something the other company can work with?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to work in the Bay Area? $150k doesn't go very far at all over there. A lot of the big tech companies are busy expanding in places like Austin, Texas where your money goes twice as far, so if you're flexible on location, I'd recommend looking around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'm thinking of asking for the 150k in exchange for scrapping the extra 200 shares and 5k signing bonus

Do that. 130K is very tight in the Bay Area! Don't count on the RSUs at all. But I hope they work out well. It commits you to the company for that time. If you don't have major stuff to tote, then you do not need 5K for the relocation.

Keep your options open down the road. Many people advance career and salary by changing companies so stay prepared to interview, always. Good luck.